# epylint in emacs using virtualenv

Tags: buildout, pylint

Can't get epylint working. I'm using buildout to generate epylint script. But then I run it from command line it doesn't output anything.

```
> epylint models.py
> echo $?
0
```

While if pylint is installed to system (emerge pylint) everything works, except system level linter does not see eggs installed by buildout. Here is my buildout part for eplint:

```
[epylint]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
    ${buildout:eggs}
    pylint
extra-paths = ${buildout:extra-paths}
entry-points = epylint=pylint.epylint:Run
```

Would like to get suggestions how I could pin point issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be due to missing pylint script, which epylint calls internally.

This buildout config works for me:

```
[epylint]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = pylint
entry-points = epylint=pylint.epylint:Run

[pylint]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = pylint
entry-points = pylint=pylint.lint:Run
arguments = sys.argv[1:]
```

I needed two parts because pylint.lint:Run and pylint.epylint:Run process command line arguments in different ways.